# vscode context menu item title

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

One of the contribution points in my extension is the `"explorer"` context menu. I noticed, context menu items take the title from `"commands"`. Is there a way to specify a different title under the context menu for the same command?

Also, is there a way to declare a command under `"commands"` section but hide it and still be able to use it under the context menu? In other words, prevent a command from displaying under the command palette but still be able to use the command for other contribution points. May be have a `"title"` property under menus and `"visible"` toggle under commands?

```
"menus": {
     "explorer/context": [
          { 
             "when": "!editorIsOpen || editorIsOpen",
             "command": "extension.myCommand",
             "title": "My Command"
          }
     ]
},
"commands": [
     { 
        "command" : "extension.myCommand", 
        "title" : "My Command with a long title",
        "visible" : false
     }
 ]
```